# Should I factor out duplication between implementation code, solely for reuse in unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, testing

I sometimes find the same block of code or same constant value duplicated between unit tests and implementation code.

In order to reuse the constants in the unit tests, I would need to make the constants something other than private.

In order to reuse the block of code, I would need to extract the block out to some place accessible by the unit tests as well.

I feel uncomfortable doing this because I am reducing encapsulation and/or removing code blocks from their context just for my unit tests.

Should I treat unit test code the same as implementation code and try to apply the DRY principle between them, or is duplication between the two desirable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends.  In general, without seeing any of your code, I would favor duplication.

Some pros are:

- tests check the code, they have a mirrored implementation so that when the code changes the tests remain static, providing the feedback and asserting things are functioning the way they are intended.  If they both shared code, and the tests called the shared code, the shared code could change, implicitly changing the test, which may result in false positives
- Using literal in tests can help for comprehensibility, when a test fails, the assertion could read cleaner.  When a human has to end up debugging all code relevant to the test could be in the body of the test method, resulting in less time spent debugging

Cons:

- Duplication! This is the major tradeoff, having an unfocused test suite could result in having to update lots of tests when production code changes

The favoring DAMP, and literals are described by Jay Fields in his book Working Effectively with Unit Tests. https://leanpub.com/wewut

After reading it, and experiencing how much more focused, and easier tests are to work with after favoring duplication (DAMP), i personally default to DAMP tests over factorying out for very DRY code, because of the numerous benefits he outlines in the book.

Comment: Thanks for commenting.  I was not aware of that the book you linked to, and think I will take the time to give it a read.